# spring-boot-configuration-processor: How to generate or provide metadata for externally provided configuration properties used with variable prefixes

Tags: spring-boot

### How to generate or provide metadata for externally provided configuration properties used with variable prefixes using the `spring-boot-configuration-processor`.

We use the configuration properties feature to bind properties multiple times using different prefixes.

```java
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "client-a")
@Bean
public MyClientProperties clientAproperties() {
  return new  MyClientProperties();
}

@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "client-b")
@Bean
public MyClientProperties clientBproperties() {
  return new  MyClientProperties();
}
```

As long as the `MyClientProperties` class is local to my spring-boot project, the `spring-boot-configuration-processor` is able to generate metadata for each prefix I use. In particular, the `description` metatdata is extracted from the field level javadoc of the class:

```java
public class MyClientProperties {
  /**
   * Web service remote endpoint url
   */
  public String endpoint = "http://localhost:8080/services";
...
}
```

The generated metadata

```
    {
      "name": "client-a.endpoint",
      "type": "java.lang.String",
      "description": "Web service remote endpoint url",
      "sourceType": "com.example.client.MyClientProperties",
      "defaultValue": "http:\/\/localhost:8080\/services"
    },
...
    {
      "name": "client-b.endpoint",
      "type": "java.lang.String",
      "description": "Web service remote endpoint url",
      "sourceType": "com.example.client.MyClientProperties",
      "defaultValue": "http:\/\/localhost:8080\/services"
    },
```

This changes as soon as the class is moved to an external jar dependency in order to be shared among several
projects and the `spring-boot-configuration-processor` has no access to the source code of the properties type.
The `description` and `defaultValue` metadata is no longer available.

```
    {
      "name": "client-a.endpoint",
      "type": "java.lang.String",
      "sourceType": "com.example.client.MyClientProperties"
    },
...
    {
      "name": "client-b.endpoint",
      "type": "java.lang.String",
      "sourceType": "com.example.client.MyClientProperties"
    },
```

If `MyClientProperties` would be used with a fixed prefix only, I could run the `spring-boot-configuration-processor`
within the external jar module and package the generated metatdata.json file. The generated metadata would be visible
in the context of the consuming spring-boot application under the `my-client` prefix.

```java
@@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my-client")
public class MyClientProperties {
...
}
```

What I need is a mechanism to access the `description` and `defaultValue` metatdata from the externally provided
properties class below the dynamic prefixes chosen by the consuming spring-boot application.

I have not found a way to make this scenario work even after extensive research. Do I oversee something or would It be better suited as an enhancement request rather than a question?

Answer (score 0):

Please consider waiting a bit before [creating an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/19500).

The annotation processor does not have access to the source model of `MyClientProperties` if that type isn't compiled alongside the `@ConfigurationProperties` use. If we don't have the source model, we don't have access to Javadoc and default values.